# How do I remove all HTML comments in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

Say I have a block like:

```
<html><!-- let's start the file -->
  <body><!-- I'm really chatty -->
  </body><!-- here's another useless comment -->
</html><!-- ok, we ended the file -->
```

I'd like to remove all the comments and I tried looking through `Edit -> Find -> Replace Structurally`.

I don't see an Existing Template to remove HTML comments under this submenu.  Is there a way to create this as a user-defined template or modify an existing one to achieve this?

Comment: What is your project's stack and what build tool are you using?

Comment: Shouldn't matter, it's an IDE question. I'm not looking to strip the comments during a build.  But it's Spring Boot.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use regular `Replace` or `Replace in Path` for this, with a regular expression search. Use the following regular expression:

```
<!--.*?-->
```

and replace with an empty string.